# Is there a way to wrap rects (or other objects) using d3

Tags: d3.js, svg

I am working on a project where I am given a list of years and I need to display them in a SVG. So far I have this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/tYEhTg680AqmPyMquAbJ?p=preview) which demos what I want to do. I render this information as follows...

```
var years = [
  2011,
  2012,
  2013,
  2014,
  2015,
  2016,
  2017,
  2018,
  2019,
  2020,
  2021,
  2022,
  2023,
  2024
];
$scope.render = function(){
  var data = $scope.svg.selectAll(".year")
    .data(years);
  data.exit().remove();
  var groups = data.enter()
                 .append("g");
  groups.append("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d, i){
      return (50 * i) + (10*i)
    })
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("height", 50)
    .attr("width", 50)
    .attr("fill", "blue")
    .attr("class", ".year");
  groups.append("text")
    .attr("x", function(d, i){
      return (50 * (i)) + (10*i) + 25
    })
    .attr("y", function(d, i){
      return 25
    })
    .attr("alignment-baseline", "middle")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(item){
      return item
    })
    .attr('fill', 'white');
}
```

This works ok until I get to a year after 2017 and then any extras just get cut off. Is there a way to wrap these? Would I need to use some sort of dragging? I would like this to work even when the screen shrinks or expands.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

A little bit of maths [can wrap them](https://plnkr.co/edit/HA5TGfV0NI88d2Ev0ujp?p=preview). A combination of % for x and / for y

```
  var years = [
    2011,
    2012,
    2013,
    2014,
    2015,
    2016,
    2017,
    2018,
    2019,
    2020,
    2021,
    2022,
    2023,
    2024
  ];
  $scope.render = function(){
    var data = $scope.svg.selectAll(".year")
      .data(years);
    data.exit().remove();
    var groups = data.enter()
                     .append("g");
    groups.append("rect")
      .attr("x", function(d, i){
        return (60 * (i % 7))
      })
      .attr("y", function(d, i) {
        return Math.floor(i / 7) * 70
      })
      .attr("height", 50)
      .attr("width", 50)
      .attr("fill", "blue")
      .attr("class", ".year");
    groups.append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d, i){
        return (60 * (i % 7)) + 25
      })
      .attr("y", function(d, i) {
        return Math.floor(i / 7) * 70 + 25
      })
      .attr("alignment-baseline", "middle")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(item){
        return item
      })
      .attr('fill', 'white');
  }
```

You could replace the hardcoded 7 I've used with a dynamic value that depends on the screen width given a little more effort.

Comment: Problems accepting at work (stupid firewall) I will def give thumbs up this looks really interesting. I will mark as the answer once I confirm. Thanks!